# "Parameter set, but not used" warning in template function

Tags: c++

I get the following `warning: parameter 'tupleValue' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]`, but the parameter is explicitly used in return statement.
Does it really mean that the return value is ignored somewhere later in the call sequence and compiler is just cool enough to optimize it out on this line?
Here is the code:

```
template<unsigned int ...Vs, class ...Ts>
typename removeLastType<Ts...>::type internalRemoveData(intValues<Vs...>, std::tuple<Ts...> tupleValue)
{
   return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Vs>(tupleValue)...);
}
```

Complete source is here: https://github.com/copperspice/cs_signal/blob/master/src/cs_internal.h#L316

Compiled in Windows:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0  
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
```

Comment: Hm... you get a copy of a tuple, take all its contents except last, put them into a tuple of references to them and return it. Maybe it doesn't like you returning a reference to a temporary?

Comment: g++ and VS compile and run it ok.

Comment: Yes, gcc 7.3 compiles it and run it without problem.

Comment: @Rinat Veliakhmedov no warnings??

Comment: @avp no warnings. I basically added: `int main() {
    std::tuple<int, char, float> a;
    [[maybe_unused]] auto b = CsSignal::Internal::funcRemoveData(a);
}` to the end of the file and put it in the compiler explorer. If you remove `maybe_unused` if shows that `b` is set but not used, but no other warnings.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov, cool, that's what seems to be the last resort. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer actually, but you have undefined behavior in your code, as @RinatVeliakhmedov has pointed out. The return value of `internalRemoveData` function is a `std::tuple`, that consist of dangling references, i.e., references to no-longer existing objects.

Consider the following simplified case:

```
struct X {
   X() { std::cout << "def ctor\n"; }
   ~X() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
   void f() { std::cout << "f\n"; }
};

template<int ...Is, class ...Ts>
auto f(std::tuple<Ts...> t) {
  return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(t)...);
}

int main() {
   auto res = f<0>(std::tuple<X>{});
   std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
   // std::get<0>(res).f(); // would use no-longer existing object 
}
```

This program prints out:

```
def ctor
dtor
---
```

After the `f` functions has finished, there does not exist any object of `X` anymore.

---

Note that this problem can be very dangerous, since the program can behave as expected. I tried it in Wandbox with uncommented `std::get<0>(res).f();` statement and the program printed out `f` and did not manifest any error. Undefined behavior includes expected behavior as well.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the authors of the original code, I think the behavior here is well defined, but the reason is a bit subtle. Here is my logic. If I have missed something, let's keep the discussion open.

The internalRemoveData method receives a tuple of values, and returns a tuple of values with exactly the same data types, minus the last element. Considering each element in the tuple separately, there are only three possible cases that matter.

1. If the element is a value type, the forward_as_tuple function will yield an lvalue reference.  This lvalue reference will be assigned to the corresponding element of the return tuple, which is a value type. This will copy from the input to the output, no dangling reference.
2. If the element is an lvalue reference, it must have already been a reference to some valid original object. It will be forwarded as an lvalue reference, which is then bound to the corresponding lvalue reference in the output.
3. If the element is an rvalue reference, it also must have already been a reference to some valid original object. We get the same behavior as the lvalue reference case.

The key to this is seeing that the return type is *not* the same as the type which forward_as_tuple returns.

If this question gets closed, look for further discussion on our YouTube channel where the original question was asked: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uK-2jzB41c4

Comment: This should be a reply to Daniel Langr's answer but apparently, I do not have enough reputation to comment. There is a small but important difference between the original code and Daniel's test code. Since the return type of `f` is being deduced with `auto`, the exact tuple created by `forward_as_tuple` is returned verbatim. This means that if the original tuple contains a value, it will be forwarded as an lvalue reference to the value from the passed tuple, which definitely will be dangling after the return. The `f` function is clearly undefined behavior if there are any value types in `Ts`.